# insert item in unsorted array

Tags: arrays, vb6

please help me solve this problem . im creating a array program in vb6 where the process is like this

- Enter size of an array: 3
- Enter elements of array: 1
- 2
- 3
- enter location of insertion: 2
- enter item to insert: 5

after insertion:

- 1
- 5
- 2
- 3

this is the code that i already did

```
Dim a(50) As Integer, n As Integer, loc As Integer, item As Integer, x As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim i As Integer
  n = InputBox("Enter Size of an Array: ", "Size")
  Text1.Text = ""
  For i = 1 To n
    a(i) = InputBox("Enter Elemets of an Array: ", "Elements")
  Next i
  location = InputBox("Enter Location of Insertion: ", "Location")
  item = InputBox("Enter Item to Insert: ", "Item")

  unsorted

  For i = 1 To n
    Text1.Text = Text1.Text + "" & a(i)
    list1.AddItem Text1.Text
    Text1.Text = ""
  Next i
End Sub

Public Sub unsorted()
  While i >= (location - 1)
    a(i + 1) = a(i)
    i = i + 1
  Wend
  a(location - 1) = item
  n = n + 1
End Sub
```

im having error in the while loop . please help me

Comment: Looks like a class assignment.  Why are you mixing the obsolete use of `+` for concatenation with its replacement `&`?  Who on Earth uses the obsolete `While...Wend` anymore?  Both of these have serious disadvantages.

Comment: btw its not concatenation i just want to add 1 to the index of the array

Comment: `Text1.Text = Text1.Text + "" & a(i)` ???  Use `Do... Loop` for looping.  Far more versatile and faster than the old `While... Wend` which is only there for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim intLoop As Integer
  Dim intA() As Integer
  ReDim intA(2) As Integer
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Dim intVal As Integer
  intA(0) = 1
  intA(1) = 2
  intA(2) = 3
  intIndex = 2
  intVal = 5
  intA = InsertVal(intA, intIndex, intVal)
  For intLoop = 0 To UBound(intA)
    Print CStr(intLoop) & " : " & CStr(intA(intLoop))
  Next intLoop
End Sub

Private Function InsertVal(intSrc() As Integer, intIndex As Integer, intVal As Integer) As Integer()
  Dim intLoop As Integer
  Dim intAdded As Integer
  Dim intResult() As Integer
  ReDim intResult(UBound(intSrc) + 1)
  intAdded = 0
  For intLoop = 0 To UBound(intSrc)
    If intLoop = intIndex Then
      intResult(intIndex) = intVal
      intAdded = intAdded + 1
    End If
    intResult(intLoop + intAdded) = intSrc(intLoop)
  Next intLoop
  InsertVal = intResult
End Function
```

Comment: i need a program that will ask the user for the size and elements of an array and what will be the location of the item that they want to insert

Comment: combine the code you posted in your question, with the code i posted in this answer .. try to understand the code, and you will see how to combine it

Answer (score 1):

I already fix it myself here's what I did

```
Dim a(50) As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim location As Integer
Dim item As Integer

Private Sub Command1_Click()
List1.Clear
Call Form_Load
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim i As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Form1.Show
n = InputBox("Enter Size of an Array: ", "Input")
If n > 50 Then
    MsgBox "The maximum size of array is 50!", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If
    For i = 1 To n
        a(i) = InputBox("Enter Elements of an array: ", "Input")
    Next i

        location = InputBox("Enter Location of insertion: ", "Input")
    If location > n Then
        MsgBox "Error! Location not possible!", vbCritical, "Warning"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        item = InputBox("Enter Item to insert: ", "Input")

insert_unsorted

'print
    For i = 1 To n
    Text1.Text = Text1.Text + "" & a(i)
    List1.AddItem Text1.Text
    Text1.Text = ""
Next i

End Sub

Public Sub insert_unsorted()
Dim i As Integer
i = n

Do While i >= location - 1
    a(i + 1) = a(i)
    i = i - 1

Loop
    a(location) = item
    n = n + 1
End Sub
```

Thanks anyway